Tailwind CSS Classes Not Applying Background Gradient in React Component
<article
  onClick={handleNavDetail}
  className={`bg-${pokemonStack?.types[0].type.name} p-3`}
>

tailwindcss: 3.4.3,
type script : Version 5.3.3,
react: 18.2.0,

If you add the classes, but you don't put the assigned colors, I am working on a React component to display Pokémon details using Tailwind CSS for styling. The classes are being added to my elements, but the background gradient styles are not being applied as expected. I'm unsure why the styles aren't reflecting in the rendered output.`
Class is assigned

I create the values

What could be causing Tailwind CSS styles not to be dynamically applied in my component?

The tailwind compiler needs to know ahead of time what classes to generate. If you are using a dynamic class, you need to tell tailwind to always generate that class. You can do that with the config file:
export default {
  ...
  safelist: ["bg-grass"]
}

See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes
You may also need to define the grass color for the bg
export default {
  ...
  theme: {
    grass: "#59842A"
  },
  safelist: ["bg-grass"]
}

Another option is to create an empty span element in your html and specify the classes you want tailwind to generate, on that span:
<span class="hidden bg-grass ..."></span>

